# Access a variable using parent reference type in java

Tags: java

I have created 2 classes - `Parent` and `Child`, both like this:

**Parent.java**

```
public class Parent {
    String name = "Parent";
}
```

**Child.java**

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    String name = "Child";
}
```

The Child class is shadowing the parent class instance variable `name`.

I have created a main program like this:

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Parent();
        Child c = new Child();

        System.out.println(p.name);
        System.out.println(c.name);

        Parent pc = new Child();
        System.out.println(pc.name);
    }

}
```

The output of the program is this:

```
Parent
Child
Parent
```

Now I am not clear on when I try to access `pc.name` then I am getting output as `Parent` as per the above output instead of `Child`.

My understanding was like this, I created a reference variable `pc` of type `Parent` but it points to `Child` object as er my program. So during run-time time of the program, java creates an object in heap memory for the child class and since the child class is shadowing the `name` variable, the output of `pc.name` will be `Child`. But as per the program my understanding was not correct and this concept applies to only methods that are overriden by child class.

Can you please explain why it is different in the case of instance variable compared to methods?

Comment: BTW, `Child extends Parent` makes no sense..

Comment: @MarounMaroun, I did'nt get you

Comment: I mean that `Child` is not necessarily a `Parent`, this is not a good example of inheritance.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, ok got it, I was just trying to see the behavior of shadowing a variable in inheritence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access to fields is always determined by the static type (that is: the type of the variable). This is in contrast to methods which are determined (a.k.a "resolved", "bound") by the runtime type of the actual object.

In other words: for field access, the compiler determines, at compilation time, is going to be accessed. In your example, you access `pc.name`. The compiler checks the type of the `pc` variable, sees that it is of type `Parent` and hence generates code that accesses the `.name` field of the `Parent` class.

Comment: Now it is clear why it is calling the parent instance variable. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

There's no overriding for instance variables.

Your `Child` class has two `name` instance variables. The one in the Child class hides the one in the Parent class (BTW, they don't have to both be of the same type).

When you access `name` via a `Parent` reference, you get the `name` variable of the `Parent` class. When you access `name` via a `Child` reference, you get the `name` variable of the `Child` class.

Comment: `BTW, they don't have to both be of the same type`, This is a good point, I don't know that. Just now verified in my program. Thank you

Comment: What does "they" mean in the answer and in the comment? You mean the name variable types, can they be String and int?

Comment: @user3320018 By "they" I mean the two variables having the same name, and yes, they can be String and int.

Comment: Great, makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Just Keep the Thumb Rule as :

1. In case of Method Overriding the reference variable does not matter but what matters is the actual object type which this variable is referring to.
2. In case of Variable Shadowing the reference variable matters while the actual object type which this variable is referring to, does not matter.

Consider the below modified classes of yours :

```
public class Parent {
    String name = "Parent";
    public void printName(){
    System.out.println("Parent Method");
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  String name = "Child";
  public void printName(){
    System.out.println("Child Method");
   }
}
```

Now will run this `main()` method in **Test Class** :-

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent p = new Parent();
    Child c = new Child();

    System.out.println(p.name); // will print Parent's name
    System.out.println(p.printName());// will call Parent
    System.out.println(c.name); // will print Child's name
    System.out.println(c.printName());// will call Child

    Parent pc = new Child();
    System.out.println(pc.name);// will print Parent's name
    System.out.println(pc.printName());// will call Child
   }
}
```

This will print the below in Accordance to the rules , which I stated above :-

```
Parent 
Parent Method
Child
Child Method
Parent
Child Method
```

Answer (score 0):

When u create a Child class object in java, internally the parent class object will also be created which would be referenced by super keyword. 
Now, using the Parent reference what all you can access from the Child class? 
Ans. Using the parent reference you can only access the inherited and overridden methods of the Child class. 
 In other words, only the methods can be invoked using the Parent reference. 
Now the Question is what happens when you use it with the variables/fields - 
Firstly, Understand how the access to variables is resolved?

Access to variables is always resolved the way static type is resolved (that is: the type of the variable) during the Compile-Time. However the methods which are determined by the runtime type of the actual object.
In this program, s.name will be resolved at the COMPILE-TIME itself. 
That is, s.name will be resolved to Shape.name
Obviously the output now has to be Shape.